# Form $_POST inaccessible SWF

Tags: php, flash

I have a swf managed with SWFObject file which send on a other page `$_POST` data. 
When I try to put `print_r($_POST)` or `$_GET`, php return me `Array()`. But on the inspector chrome, `$_POST` are here.

```
"Form data" : 
onData:[type Function]
__app_key:be86b85e5b
code:b1512Xs05015s09153s09018s04144
groupId:8954
```

`$_POST` data are sent but I can't use them.

Comment: What are the values of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` here? `$_POST` will only be populated when the Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is empty and CONTENT_TYPE doesn't exist.       More info on chrome : Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded One of my idea is that crossdomain isn't call. On a other website which has the same swf, it call crossdomain and it works.